# Summation\ Addition of two arrays (particular)

Tags: javascript, arrays

"A positive number of whatever length is represented as an array of numerical characters, ergo between '0's and '9's. We know that the most significant cypher is in position of index 0 of the array.

Example:
 - Number is 10282
 - Array will be   number = [1,0,2,8,2]

This considered, create a function of 2 arrays representing two positive numbers that calculates the SUM\ADDITION\SUMMATION of both of them and set it in a third array, containing the sum of the first 2."

This is how the exercise is translated from my own language, italian.

This is my solution but it doesnt entirely work. I have tried with basic stuff like
A=[1,4] and B=[4,7]. The results should be C=[6,1] but it gives me [5,1] as it considers the line where I use the modular but not the one where I say that the -1 index position should take a ++.

Help <3

```
alert('Insert A length');
var k=asknum();
alert('Insert B length');
var h=asknum();
var A = new Array(k);
var B = new Array(h);
// asknum() is only defined in this particular environment we are
// using at the university. I guess the turnaround would be -prompt- 

function readVet(vet){//inserts values in index positions
  for(i=0;i<vet.length;i++)
    vet[i]=asknum();
}


readVet(A);//fills array
readVet(B);//fills array


function sumArray(vet1,vet2){
  var C = new Array();
  for(i=vet1.length-1;i>(-1);i--){
    for(n=vet2.length-1;n>(-1);n--){
      C[i]=vet1[i]+vet2[i];
      if(C[i]>9){
        C[i]=C[i]%10;
        C[i-1]=C[i-1]++;
    }
  }
  }
  return C;
}

print(sumArray(A,B));
```

Comment: Why should `A=[1,4] and B=[4,7]` equal `C=[6,1]`? I don't understand the math here.

Comment: Why two for loops here? Just calculate the length of the two arrays and get the maximum length and do one loop for addition

Comment: If you have figured out your solution, please post an answer; do not edit your question with the solution.

Comment: Please do not repost questions. Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366412/sum-up-2-arrays-considering-their-decimal-values) was closed because you failed to provide a clear explanation of the problem or demonstrate any effort to solve it. In the future, instead of reposting, you should edit the question to include the relevant information. Failing to do so may lead to downvotes, closures, and eventually, a question ban.

Comment: sorry everyone! Ill try to stay by the rules next time I post. Best regards <3

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing with a nested `for` loop here.  You just need one.  Also, to make said loop really simple, normalize the arrays first so that both are the length of the larger array + 1 element (in case of carry).  Then correct the result on the way out of the function.

```
function normalizeArray(array, digits) {
    var zeroCnt = digits - array.length,
        zeroes = [];
    while (zeroCnt--) {
        zeroes.push(0);
    }
    return zeroes.concat(array);
}

function sumArrays(a1, a2) {
    var maxResultLength = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length) + 1;

    a1 = normalizeArray(a1, maxResultLength);
    a2 = normalizeArray(a2, maxResultLength);
    var result = normalizeArray([], maxResultLength);

    var i = maxResultLength - 1, // working index
        digit = 0,               // working result digit
        c = 0;                   // carry (0 or 1)

    while (i >= 0) {
        digit = a1[i] + a2[i] + c;
        if (digit > 9) {
            c = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        } else {
            c = 0;
        }
        result[i--] = digit;
    }

    /* If there was no carry into the most significant digit, chop off the extra 0 */
    /* If the caller gave us arrays with a bunch of leading zeroes, chop those off */
    /* but don't be an idiot and slice for every digit like sqykly =D */
    for (i = 0 ; i < result.length && result[i] === 0 ; i++) {
        /* result = result.slice(1); don't do that, or anything */
    }
    return result.slice(i);
}
```

That gives the expected output.

Comment: Amazing help from you guys. Much love!

Comment: +1 This is the most efficient solution! One addition: it could be better to normalize only the smaller array to the length of the larger one. You don't need to iterate over result to fill with 0, as they will be overwritten. You can result.unshift(1) if there is a carry. Those array copies can hurt if the arrays are big!

Comment: @Tibos My first draft (not answer, just what I ran in Firebug to see if it worked) didn't iterate at the end, but I realized it was a hazard for input that had a bunch of leading `0` elements.  This way, if I need to add `subtractArrays` or take arbitrary user input, I don't have to bother checking for that.  If I did start adding other methods, I would probably move that loop out to its own function or do it in `normalizeArray`, anyway, though.  `unshift` might hurt if the array is big, too.

Comment: @Tibos I just looked up and realized I was using `slice` in a loop - my bad, that is really inefficient.  Will fix by iteratively scanning for the first non-zero digit, then `slice`ing once.

Answer (score 1):

I followed a different approach that may very well be less efficient than yours, but i consider it to be much clearer. One important thing is that i reverse the arrays so the least significant bit is first. Comments are in the code.

```
function sum(a,b){
  // ensure a is the largest of the two arrays
  if (a.length < b.length)
    return sum(b,a);

  // flip the arrays so the least significant digit is first
  a = a.reverse();
  b = b.reverse();

  // c will hold the result (reversed at first)
  var c = [];

  // add each number individually
  var carry = a.reduce(function(carry,digitA,index){
    // digitA is guaranteed to be a number, digit from b is not!
    var sum = digitA + (b[index] || 0) + carry;
    c.push(sum%10);
    return Math.floor(sum/10); // this is carried to the next step of the addition
  },0); // initial carry is 0

  if (carry) c.push(1); // resolve if carry exists after all digits have been added

  return c.reverse();
}

// Usage:
console.log(sum([1,0,8,3],[1,3,5])); // [1, 2, 1, 8]
console.log(sum([8,3],[7,9])); // [1, 6, 2]
```

PS: There are many problems with your code. For one, you cannot use two nested loops:

```
var a = [0,1];
var b = [2,3];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
    console.log(a[i] + ' ' + b[i]);
  }
}
// will output: 0 2, 0 3, 1 2, 1 3
// you want something along the lines of: 0 2, 1 3
```

What you want is a single loop that iterates over both arrays simultaneously.

My attempt at an efficient solution:

```
function efficientSum(a,b){
  var i = a.length, j = b.length;
  if (i<j) return efficientSum(j,i);
  var q = 0, c = [];
  c.length = i;
  while (i) {
    c[--i] = a[i] + (b[--j] || 0) + q;
    q = c[i] > 9 ? ((c[i]-=10),1) : 0; // comma operator, ugly!
  }
  if (q) c.unshift(1);
  return c;
}
```

Comment: I added a more efficient solution that iterates over all 3 arrays in parallel. There is as little array manipulation as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something because the other answers look much more complicated, but here's my attempt at providing an answer based on the question:

```
// Takes an array and generates the sum of the elements
function addArrayNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, c) { 
    return String(p) + String(c);
  });
}

// Sums two numbers and returns an array based on that sum
function addCombinedNumbers(a, b) {
  return String(Number(a) + Number(b)).split('');
}

var arrone = [1, 4];
var arrtwo = [4, 7];

var one = addArrayNumbers(arrone);
var two = addArrayNumbers(arrtwo);

var c = addCombinedNumbers(one, two); // [6,1]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBRPf/24/)

Comment: The thing you are missing is that the other answers work for any length numbers (as long as there space to represent them in an array), while yours converts the arrays to numbers (64bit floating points), making them subject to their restrictions.

Comment: Also, a `addArrayNumbers(arr)` can be simplified to `arr.join('')`, giving a shorter solution as: `var c = (+a.join('') + +b.join('') + '').split('').map(function(item){return +item});`. I used unary `+` to convert to number and `+''` to convert to String and also converted all the digits in the result to actual numbers (they are strings in your solution).